# Using reflection , is there a way to get the fields of the superclass?

Tags: java, reflection, superclass

I am using reflection to get the DeclaredFields of a particular class. Is there a way to be able to retrieve the fields of the superclass for a particular class?

Comment: the answer is yes, but you should have tried this out yourself before asking here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried.

```
myClass.getSuperClass().getDeclaredFields();
```